# Como alterar valores de somente uma coluna em uma matriz (Python PURO)

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um trabalho de programação em Python PURO (ou seja, não é permitido usar Pandas/Numpy) cuja primeira parte é, em uma matriz, substituir determinados valores por determinados números.

Por exemplo: na matriz

```
f s g t f f c
x f g t n f c
f y n t n f c
```

, preciso analisar cada linha e, no primeiro elemento de cada linha,

- Se o elemento for "b", substituir por 0;
- Se o elemento for "c", substituir por 1;
- Se o elemento for "x", substituir por 2;
- entre outras letras específicas, assim por diante.

Porém, no segundo elemento de cada linha, a regra das letras é diferente, eu preciso analisar outras letras.

Então, pesquisei e tentei usar a Compreensão de Listas do Python:

```
for j in [x[0] for x in matriz]:
    if j == 'b':
        j = "0"
        j = int(j) # transforma string em inteiro
        
    elif j == 'c':
        j = "1"
        j = int(j)
        
    elif j == 'x':
        j = "2"
        j = int(j)
        

for j in [x[1] for x in matriz]:
    if j == 'f':
        j = "0"
        j = int(j)
        
    elif j == 'g':
        j = "1"
        j = int(j)
        
    elif j == 'y':
        j = "2"
        j = int(j)
        
    elif j == 's':
        j = "3"
        j = int(j)
```

Mas não deu certo. Fiz um print do `j` em cada `if` depois que ele substitui o valor, ele mostra o valor inteiro, mas não substitui na matriz, e assim ela continua a mesma.

Comment: A única condição é não usar bibliotecas?

Comment: @HenriqueHott sim, não posso usar módulos ou bibliotecas além das bibliotecas padrão do Python.

Comment: Então acredito que minha resposta esteja correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é trabalhar com dicionário, por causa do sistema de key: value.

Ele funciona bem por diversos motivos como, por exemplo, o código fica mais fácil de ler, pois não tem vários `if` e `elif`.

Basicamente o que acontece é:

1. Percorrer cada linha da matriz:

```py
for linha in matriz:
```

2. Percorrer cada letra da linha, usando a função range(), pois ela que vai retornar o número inteiro que permitira acessar o valor da linha da forma correta possibilitando atribuições:

```py
for letra in range(len(linha)):
```

3. Depois de criado os laços, tem que testar a condição, que no caso é: Se a letra estiver no dicionário. E se for verdade, fazer a substituição do item da lista pelo valor no dicionário.

```py
if linha[letra] in tradutor:
   linha[letra] = tradutor[linha[letra]]
```

Código completo:

```py
matriz = [
    ['f', 's', 'g', 't', 'f', 'f', 'c'],
    ['x', 'f', 'g', 't', 'n', 'f', 'c'],
    ['f', 'y', 'n', 't', 'n', 'f', 'c']
]

tradutor = {'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'x': 2}

for linha in matriz:
    for letra in range(len(linha)):
        if linha[letra] in tradutor:
            linha[letra] = tradutor[linha[letra]]
```

Comment: Se minha resposta estiver correta, por favor, marcar como correta.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu (com alguns ajustes)!